# Angular 2 new (RC1) router. Second level router-outlet works only once

Tags: angular, nested, router

Here's the plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/B8feYX7e6oxvI2u4zmYW/

Click on "Child 1" - works. Now click on "Child 2" - does not work.
Click "HOME".
Click on "Child 2" - works. Now click on "Child 1" - does not work.

Basically navigation from app root to nested router outlet works only once per app life or until you mandatory navigate back to the root first.

Here's some of the code (look at the plunker for the full version):

**app.component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <div>
      <a [routerLink]="['/']">HOME</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/child', 1]">Child 1</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/child', 2]">Child 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})

@Routes([
    { path: 'child/:id', component: ChildContainerComponent }
])    

export class AppComponent { }
```

**child-container.component**

```
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
 <div>
    <h3>Child outer container</h3>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
`
})

@Routes([
    { path: '/', component: ChildComponent }
])

export class ChildContainerComponent{
}
```

**child.component**

```
@Component({
    template: `
<div>
    Child: Id={{_id}}
</div>
`
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    private _id: number;

    private get routeSegment(): RouteSegment {  // must be better way to get value
        return this._router.routeTree._root.children[0].value;
    }

    constructor(private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._id = +this.routeSegment.getParam('id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your AppComponent Routes to:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/child', component: ChildContainerComponent }
])
```

And your ChildContainerComponent Routes to:

```
@Routes([
    { path: ':id', component: ChildComponent }
])
```

Once you have these routes you can get the Id by implementing `OnActivate` interface:

```
import { Router, RouteSegment, RouteTree, OnActivate, Routes } from '@angular/router';

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnActivate {
    private _id: number;

    routerOnActivate(currRoute: RouteSegment, 
                     prevRoute?: RouteSegment, 
                     currTree?: RouteTree, 
                     prevTree?: RouteTree) {

        this._id = +currRoute.getParam('id');
    }
}
```

Here is a working [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8xx3UobiKK8OgvCUzbQ?p=preview)

Comment: That seems to work, but why in my case it also works but only once?

Comment: I think it only works if you are at the route of your app and that has to do with how the RC1 Router builds routes incrementally as you go deep into your links.

Comment: Found even shorter version of getting param on github:  constructor(private _router: Router, private _segment: RouteSegment) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._id = +this._segment.getParam('id');
    }

Comment: Now, if we want to redirect from one child to another - how to do it right?
I added a button within 'child' to navigate to another component and having issues again.
Here's the plunker.
[link](http://embed.plnkr.co/7rUpBQFjlo5VHhofgPbM/)